# Geofence library in Java

Tags: java, android-geofence

Do you know java open source geofence library (Determining Whether A Point Is Inside A Complex Polygon) like Google play services for Android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look https://code.google.com/p/openmap/source/browse/src/openmap/com/bbn/openmap/geo/Intersection.java

> public static boolean isPointInPolygon(Geo x, GeoArray poly)

Answer (score 3):

use a open source library call "utils" http://www.geotelematic.com/javadocs/org/opengts/util/package-summary.html

> boolean  isPointInside(GeoPoint gp) 
>             Returns true if the specified point is inside the polygon

.
include in OpenGts Proyect : http://www.opengts.org/

```
import org.opengts.util.GeoPoint;

import org.opengts.util.GeoPolygon;
```

use this snipet to check if Point is inside a Polygon

```
    GeoPolygon fence = new GeoPolygon( // Define a Fence Polygon 
            new GeoPoint(-31.414547, -64.488178),
            new GeoPoint(-31.415579, -64.496261),
            new GeoPoint(-31.411513, -64.495720),
            new GeoPoint(-31.408726, -64.489549),
            new GeoPoint(-31.411898, -64.484406)
            );

    GeoPoint testgp1 = new GeoPoint(-31.411753, -64.489922);// Point1 inside
    GeoPoint testgp2 = new GeoPoint(-31.413962, -64.486445);// Point2 outside


    boolean inzone = fence.isPointInside(testgp1);
    System.out.println ("Point1 is inside of polygon= "+inzone);
    inzone = fence.isPointInside(testgp2);
    System.out.println ("Point2 is inside of polygon= "+inzone);
```

result:

```
Point1 is inside of polygon= true
Point1 is inside of polygon= false
```

Comment: I suppose that these library don`t have separate maven jar including this "utils" package but I will try it thanks!

Comment: does not have.
in my case I only include the ' org.opengts.util ' folder in my project.
If you only need the function ' isPointInside ()', this depends on ' GeoPoint.java / GeoPolygon.java ' .
But I recommend include the whole package and that has functions , methods and classes very useful .
As you can see if you take a look.
The author states: "Contains various common use utilities that make programming a little easier."

Comment: The same think like openmap I think that initial code of opengts have very common thinks like https://github.com/OpenMap-java/openmap/blob/master/src/openmap/com/bbn/openmap/geo/Intersection.java

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Maps Android API utility library: containsLocation](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#containsLocation(LatLng,%20java.util.List,%20boolean)).

Comment: Yes but do you have source code of PolyUtils class? ;)